# How to structure dynamic event insertion for a calendar in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a general outline of the best way to structure this type of logic in angular.

**What I'm doing**

I'm rending a calendar in HTML and need to insert event objects from a list of events in their respective day elements.

**What I would do in jQuery**

Using jquery in the past, I would first create a unique slug class for each day element like `class="day_01_12_2014"` during the calendar render. I would then loop through each event and insert the event by recreating the unique slug ie: `$('.day_'+e.day+'_'+e.month+'+'_'+e.year).append(event_html);`

**What I think* I want to do in angular**

The only way I could imagine this is to basically have a bunch of scope aware day directives that basically 'listens' to the array of events and then inserts it into itself it one matches the date that it represents. What would this directive look like or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Is the loop and insert a viable method using angular? I feel like this is not angular's style. Or should I be using a directive to somehow know if an event inside an array is on it's own respective day?

The directive I'm thinking would basically create a $watch($scope.events) and then loop though and render the html as necessary? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are you writing your own calendar or do you use an existing one like fullcalendar/ui-calendar?

Comment: I'm writing my own calendar. I have access to how it gets formatted but it comes in as a pre rendered html block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely do this with a directive.

Here's one way you could do it:

```
<calendar month="03" year="2014"></calendar>
```

The **calendar** directive I've made accepts a month and year as a parameter. You could also pass it your events, but I've just put them on the scope by utilising a controller on a parent element:

```
.controller('CalendarControl', ($scope)->

  $scope.events = [

    {
      date: '2014-03-20'
      name: 'today!'
    },
    {
      date: '2014-03-21'
      name: 'tomorrow'
    },
    {
      date: '2014-03-29'
      name: 'My birthday!'
    }

  ]

)
```

Then using the following template for the directive:

```
<div class="calendar-day" ng-repeat="day in monthDays track by $index">
  {{ $index + 1 }}
  <div class="event" ng-repeat="event in getEventsForDay($index + 1)">
    {{event.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and this code:

```
.directive('calendar', ()->

  restrict: 'E'
  templateUrl: 'calendar.html'

  link: (scope, element, attributes)->

    # add some logic here to inspect attributes.month and get the correct number
    # of days in the month.
    # This is just bodged.
    scope.monthDays = new Array(31);

    scope.month = attributes.month
    scope.year = attributes.year

    scope.getEventsForDay = (day)->
      _.where(scope.events, { 'date': [scope.year, scope.month, day].join('-')})

)
```

Your directive will create a `div` for every day in the month, then inside that, it will create another `div` for every event on that day.

[Here's a working example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xj1sSNKXX0IpZxJSvS4l?p=preview)

You'll notice that no `$watch`es at all are required, which (I think) is a good thing. Use the form at the bottom to add an event, (note I haven't gone to any effort to validate the date or anything, so make sure you enter it in the right format).